# Store data from a Next.js server-side component in Jotai

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a server component that consists of a fetch request to get data, for example, categories. The fetch function on the server side works as expected but I need somehow to store this data in a store/state that my whole website can access.

```js
import { atom, useAtom } from "jotai";
import MainNav2Logged from "./MainNav2Logged";

export interface HeaderLoggedProps {}
const categoriesAtom = atom([]);

async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch("https://api.escuelajs.co/api/v1/categories");
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }
  const data = await res.json();
  categoriesAtom.set(data); // here is the problem
}

const HeaderLogged = () => {
  const categories = useAtom(categoriesAtom);
  return (
    <div className="nc-HeaderLogged sticky top-0 w-full z-40 ">
      <MainNav2Logged />
      {categories.map((el) => (
        <p key={el.id}>is it here? {el.name}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default HeaderLogged;
```

But it gave me this error:

```
You're importing a component that needs useEffect. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.

       ,-[/home/ash/Desktop/diffandyol/node_modules/jotai/esm/react.mjs:1:1]
     1 | import ReactExports, { createContext, useContext, useRef, createElement, useReducer, useEffect, useDebugValue, useCallback } from 'react';
       :                                                                                      ^^^^^^^^^
     2 | import { getDefaultStore, createStore } from 'jotai/vanilla';
     3 | 
     4 | const StoreContext = createContext(void 0);
       `----
    
    The error was caused by importing 'jotai/esm/index.mjs' in './src/components/Header/HeaderLogged.tsx'.
```

By the way, I use the Next.js experimental App router, not the Pages router.

Comment: Hi EshgheCode! Check the answer to the linked thread please. In the end, it treats your problem, setting up a store.